# Replace only some of a specific character without replacing all of the characters

Tags: c#

**Updated:**
I have my program reading a json file and after it reads it spits out several lines from the file. One of them being "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1". I need a way to replace all the "." before the ":" with "\" as well as replace all the ":" with "\" This should create something that look like this "org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1" which would then be used to create the directory. For example:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("org\\apache\\commons\\commons-compress\\1.8.1");
```

**Original:**
I have my program reading a json file and after it reads it spits out several lines from the file. One of them being org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1 this text is then used to make a folder system. However there is a problem when trying to change the given text into a folder to be created, the end product should be "org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1". But from what I have seen you can only change all of the "." So what I am looking for is a way to only change the "." before the ":" and then change the ":" to "\" as well.
Thanks for the help in advance, if you need me to clarify anything just ask.

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what you want to do - there are _two_ colons in your example input

Comment: @stuartd ok I will try and make it more clear and will update the question.

Comment: Although it seems my answer does what you need, I think your updated explanation is still not clear as you don't differentiate between both ':'. I always the last ':' the *token* that separates the string?

Comment: *I meant "Is always the last ':'...

Comment: @stuartd <package>:<name>:<version> This is the best I could give you as I am not the one who designed the json file I am reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do what you need:

```
string source = @"org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1";
int lastColon = source.LastIndexOf(':') + 1;
string path = source.Substring(0, lastColon).Replace('.', '\\').Replace(':', '\\');
path += source.Substring(lastColon);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

It looks for the position of the last colon, replaces the necessary characters up to that point (the +1 is to include this colon) and then just adds the remaining characters unchanged.

If you don't want to hardcode the `\`, you can use `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead.